# Xcode cannot connect to IOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Recently, i often get an error when compile to the simulator:
[image: error pic]

My solution is to close the simulator and re-compile the app, most of the time, it works. But this is annoying for me. Is there any better solution?

Env:

- Xcode version:6.1.1
- Simulator version8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve the issue in some more type

**choice - 1**

> Restart Mac can solve the problem for me.

**choice - 2**

> In this case,tried to run the app on a iPhone 6 simulator when I got this error. Quitted the simulator only and re-ran the app on iPhone 5s (8.1) - it worked fine.
>
> After a while I changed the target back to iPhone 6 (without quitting it), and ran the app against it - no error shown..

**choice no-3**

> iOS Simulator > Reset Contents and Settings...

Comment: Thanks for your experience :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your simulator

IOS Simulator => reset content and settings..